# Need help in Jquery to fill data-value

Tags: jquery

I have a select field in my form like the following:

- Select an Option -
  Shop 1
  Shop 2
  Shop 1

And I have another field that I want to fill the value from the select above using the data-value not "value"

ID of field I want filled in by the select above: #j2store_jformattribsj2storevendor_id

My Code:

```
jQuery("#shop").on("keyup", function(){
jQuery("#j2store_jformattribsj2storevendor_id").val(jQuery("data-value").val());
});
```

Any help would be ideal!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jQuery("data-value")` cannot be right!
if you have one element with `id="your_element" data-value="something"` you can do

```
jQuery("#shop").on("keyup", function(){
 jQuery("#j2store_jformattribsj2storevendor_id").val(jQuery("#your_element").attr("data-value"));
});
```